# display html stored in xml using razor view engine

Tags: html, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am storing some html inside an xml document similar to this:

```
<news>
    <item>
        <title>some title</title>
        <story>some text<![CDATA[<p/>]]> some more text</story>
    </item>
</news>
```

I read the xml into a model object that is used in an MVC 3 view with razor syntax.
Everything displays fine except the html that I have in the CData sections is printed to the screen as is similar to this:

**some title**

some text`<p/>`some more text

My view looks like this:

```
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<p>
    @Model.Story
</p>
```

but obviously i'm missing something on the rendering of the story. I even tried doing a `@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Story)` but that gave me the same result.

How can I get it to render this?

**some title**

some text

some more text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Html.Raw`](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx) helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Story)
```